# Self-adjoint extensions modern paper or book

Tags: reference-request, operator-theory

Do you know some modern and recent paper, lecture notes, or book about self-adjoint extension theory (defect indeces, Von Neumann theory,...)?

Classical references can also be helpful but I am searching for some modern and advanced review (if possible with examples).

Answer (score 2):

Some recent papers:

Sebestyén, Zoltán; Stochel, Jan [Characterizations of positive selfadjoint extensions](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/2007-135-05/S0002-9939-06-08590-X/home.html). Proc. Amer. Math. Soc. 135 (2007), no. 5, 1389–1397

Sebestyén, Z.; Tarcsay, Zs. [T∗T always has a positive selfadjoint extension](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10474-011-0154-7). Acta Math. Hungar. 135 (2012), no. 1-2, 116–129.

Malamud, Mark M.; Neidhardt, Hagen [On the unitary equivalence of absolutely continuous parts of self-adjoint extensions](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022123610004234). J. Funct. Anal. 260 (2011), no. 3, 613–638.

Answer (score 2):

Schmudgen's "Unbounded Self-adjoint Operators on Hilbert spaces" may address some of your interests. Also G. Grubb's "Distributions and Operators".